# Replace a list of characters with indices in a string in python

Tags: python

I have a list of coordinates:

```
coordinates = [[1,5], [10,15], [25, 35]]
```

I have a string as follows:

```
line = 'ATCACGTGTGTGTACACGTACGTGTGNGTNGTTGAGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT'
```

I want to replace intervals indicated in pairs in `coordinates` as start and end with character `'N'`.

The only way I can think of is the following:

```
for element in coordinates:
    length = element[1] - element[0]
    line = line.replace(line[element[0]:element[1]], 'N'*length)
```

The desired output would be:

```
line = 'ANNNNGTGTGNNNNNACGTACGTGTNNNNNNNNNNGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT'
```

where intervals, [1,5), [10,15) and [25, 35) are replaced with `N` in `line`.

This requires me to loop through the coordinate list and update my string line, every time. I was wondering if there is another way that one can replace a list of intervals in a string?

Note: There is a problem with the original solution in this question. In `line.replace(line[element[0]:element[1]], 'N'*length)`, `replace` will replace all other instances of string identical to the one in `line[element[0]:element[1]]` from the sequence and for people working with DNA, this is definitely not what you want! I however, keep the solution as it is to not disturb the flow of comments and discussion following.

Comment: Please add example (desired) output to the question.

Comment: But I think this should do what you want: `for start, end in coordinates: line = line[:start] + "N" * (end - start) + line[end:]` -- if I've correctly understood.

Comment: I am not sure your current solution even does what you expect. `replace` replaces **all** occurrences of the sub-string so it *might* not only replace the indices you give it

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh, really, that's so important. It looks in my example is working correctly with the indices I give to it. How do you think it could cause a problem? Is there another method I could use instead?

Comment: I think what Tome is trying to ask is if the program should replace all occurences of "TCAC" (Indices 1 through 5) or just from indices 1 through 5.

Comment: @Homap it *__might__* cause a problem if for example the substring between indices `1` and `5` (`TCAC`) appears somewhere else in the string, so it will be replaced as well. That might not be what you want

Comment: @Tomerikoo This is so important. I will add this as a note to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JimmyCarlos Definitely only from indices 1 through 5, not all the occurrences. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of string concatenation (wich is wasteful due to created / destroyed string instances), use a list:

```
coordinates = [[1,5], [10,15], [25, 35]] # sorted

line = 'ATCACGTGTGTGTACACGTACGTGTGNGTNGTTGAGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT'

result = list(line)
# opted for exclusive end pos
for r in [range(start,end) for start,end in coordinates]:
    for p in r:
        result[p]='N'

res = ''.join(result)
print(res)
```

To get:

```
ANNNNGTGTGNNNNNACGTACGTGTNNNNNNNNNNGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT
```

---

optimized to use slicing and exclusive `end`:

```
for start,end in coordinates:
    result[start:end] = ["N"]*(end-start)

res = ''.join(result)
print(line)
print(res)
```

gives you your wanted output:

```
ATCACGTGTGTGTACACGTACGTGTGNGTNGTTGAGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT 
ANNNNGTGTGNNNNNACGTACGTGTNNNNNNNNNNGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT
```

Comment: This solution took about 89 seconds on 2.4 GB file.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, this should work.

```
coordinates = [[1,5], [10,15], [25, 35]]
line = 'ATCACGTGTGTGTACACGTACGTGTGNGTNGTTGAGTGKWSGTGAAAAAKCT'
for L,R in coordinates:
    line = line[:L] + "N"*(R-L) + line[R:]
print(line)
```

You may need to adjust this depending on how the coordinates are defined, eg. inclusive/1-indexed.

We need more people working with DNA, so great work.

Comment: Good. The code in the question would probably imply that the indices should be as you have now shown (and I thought the same - see my comment under the question) but some example output from the OP would certainly help clarify this.

Comment: Ah, now we have example output in the question, and it is as suspected.